# duplicate maximum values from sql server

Tags: sql-server

```
date    maxval
19/08/2015  1
19/08/2015  2
19/08/2015  2
19/08/2015  1
20/08/2015  6
20/08/2015  7
20/08/2015  8
20/08/2015  9
```

Desired output
               date    maxval
           19/08/2015   2
           19/08/2015   2
           20/08/2015   9

required duplicate maximum values like if 19/08/2015 in 6 is an max values but i have duplicate so required both max and 20/08/2015 have only one max value so it displaying one max val please how we can get from sql server query.

"

Comment: Could you post your desired output? If you have already made an attempt at solving this, your attempt would also be quite useful as it might convey your intentions better than the explanation in the question?

Answer (score 1):

Here is your query

```
Select date, max(maxval) 
from tab
group by date
order by date
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`DENSE_RANK()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms173825.aspx) to give each record a rank within each date. Then simply filter the records for the top 1 (`WHERE t.dr = 1`). Using `DENSE_RANK()` rather than [`ROW_NUMBER()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx) will allow for duplicates:

```
SELECT  Date, MaxVal
FROM    (   SELECT  Date, 
                    MaxVal,
                    dr = DENSE_RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY Date ORDER BY MaxVal DESC)
            FROM    YourTable
        ) AS t
WHERE   t.dr = 1;
```

Comment: Hi please check below query and desired output

Comment: SELECT  timetag, proceed15mindata
FROM    (   SELECT  convert(date,timetag)as timetag, max(proceed15mindata)  as proceed15mindata, dr = DENSE_RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY timetag ORDER BY proceed15mindata DESC)
            FROM    T_EMS_VGDM_VGPROCEEDDATA where PROCEED15MINDATA is not null group by timetag, proceed15mindata
        ) AS t
WHERE   t.dr = 1 

select * from T_EMS_VGDM_VGPROCEEDDATA

Comment: 2015-08-19 6
2015-08-19 6
2015-08-19 6
2015-08-20 6.12999999523163
2015-08-20 6.125
2015-08-20 6.1089999973774
2015-08-20 6.097999997437
2015-08-20 6.10400000214577
2015-08-20 6.10000000149012
2015-08-20 6.11299999803305
2015-08-20 6
2015-08-20 6.09399999678135
2015-08-20 6

Comment: @LalitSharma Please don't post results or code as comments, there is no support for formatting. If you are having further issues from my solution, please edit your question, and add the formatted code, and result to that so it is easily legible. I am also not sure what problem you are having, with your example data the query above gives you the right output - [Example on SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/3d8f4/1)